# css - как сделать увеличение процентов при уменшения екрану?

Tags: css

У меня есть position-absolute, и задано left:30%.И мне надо чтоб когда была ширина экрану меньше 768px left:30% увеличивался например на 0.1% при уменьшения экрану, как записать формулу в css такую?)

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
           code...     
             }
```

Comment: `767px → 30.1%`, `766px → 30.2%` — таким образом?

Comment: да так, что то пробувал писать , делить ,потом множить на ширину , не получалось. Плохо с математикой у меня), просто адаптивный надо процент под ширину сделать

Comment: @MaksymGapachilo, а использовать [единицы измерения](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units) `vw`, `vh`, `vmin`, `vmax` не пробовали?

Comment: незнаю как они работают, адаптивная единица или как те что вы перечислили?

Comment: Я добавил ссылку в прошлый комментарий. Да, это специфичные размеры, например, `50vw` означает 50% от ширины окна, `33vh` - это треть от высоты окна, `10vmin` - это 10% от ширины окна (если включена портретная ориентация) или 10% от высоты окна (если включена горизонтальная ориентация)